# How can I detect socket closure with a SocketAsyncEventArgs?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, c++-cli

I'm running into an interesting scenario when I'm trying to roll with .Net's SocketAsyncEventArgs. Namely, the fact that they can't seem to detect when a graceful remote socket shutdown has occurred.

Bit of background: I'm updating a legacy application from MFC to a .NET project, and my code needs to interface with all other legacy MFC code. In the legacy MFC code, the MFC backend automatically registers when a remote connection is gracefully closed with a FIN or RST signal. I've observed this behavior in action, and all the user can or needs to interact with is overloading the OnClose method that MFC provides.

I can't replicate that in C# or C++/CLI at the moment. My SocketAsyncEventArgs that I use to handle all receive operations looks like this:

```
static void AcceptHandler(System::IAsyncResult^ ar)
{
    ServerSocket ^server = (ServerSocket ^)ar->AsyncState;
    try
    {
       server->Socket = gcnew SocketMgr(server->listener->EndAcceptSocket(ar));
       //pConnectionCb a function variable I use for updating the GUI when
       //connection status changes. ReceiveDataHandler is another function
       //variable for logging purposes.
       if (server->pConnectionChangedCb)
       {
          server->pConnectionChangedCb(server->nID);
       }

       if (server->receiveDataHandler)
       {
          System::Net::Sockets::SocketAsyncEventArgs ^receiveArgs = gcnew System::Net::Sockets::SocketAsyncEventArgs();
          receiveArgs->SetBuffer(server->readbuffer, server->nOffset, server->nBytesToGet - server->nOffset);
          receiveArgs->Completed +=
              gcnew System::EventHandler<System::Net::Sockets::SocketAsyncEventArgs ^>(server, &ServerSocket::IO_Completed);
          server->Socket->ReceiveAsync(receiveArgs);
      }
   }
   catch (System::Net::Sockets::SocketException ^e)
   {
      System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("OnAccept: Could not Accept, exception" + e->ErrorCode);
      server->listener->EndAcceptSocket(ar);
   }
}
void IO_Completed(System::Object ^sender, System::Net::Sockets::SocketAsyncEventArgs ^e)
{
   if (!(e->SocketError == System::Net::Sockets::SocketError::Success))
   {
      kPrintf("Error.");
   }
   // determine which type of operation just completed and call the associated handler
   switch (e->LastOperation)
   {
   case System::Net::Sockets::SocketAsyncOperation::Receive:
      ProcessReceive(e);
      break;
   case System::Net::Sockets::SocketAsyncOperation::Send:
      ProcessSend(e);
      break;
   default:
      throw gcnew System::ArgumentException("The last operation completed on the socket was not a receive or send");
   }
};
```

From what I've observed, when the remote socket ceases to exist, the SocketAsyncEventArgs object in the middle of the read exists in a state where it has not been completed, and will never be completed. As it fails to complete, IO_Completed will never be called, and I will be unable to use this to detect when a socket sends a graceful disconnect. So it can't be used.

...The only problem with this being, of course, that there's no OnRemoteClose (or equivalent) event for me to scribe to in Socket.Net.Sockets.Socket or in the SocketAsyncEventArgs, leaving me unable to detect a socket FIN or RST signal and keeping the socket open longer than expected. C# probably has a way around this, but I can't, for the life of me, find it. Anyone else wrestled with this before?

Comment: This works for me. If I issue ReceiveAsync() as you have done, when the client socket shuts down, the Completed event handler fires as expected.

Comment: That said, I would suggest, if you can, to use the more modern TcpClient, Stream, and Task-based async IO.

Comment: Huh. It might be an artifact of the MFC framework on the client side that's causing this, that I'm trying to debug. Grr.

Comment: @glenebob do you have advice on where to look for good introductions to TcpClient, Stream, or Task-based async IO?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the fact you're using c++, which does not support the `await` pattern (you would need to write in c#). Moving to Task-based IO isn't all that beneficial without `await`.

Comment: In what cases would using the await operator be more useful than calling the equivalent synchronous method?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, SocketAsyncEventArgs does record a graceful termination of any remote socket, regardless of client language. It does not expose the underlying TCP/IP events or anything similar, and instead just demonstrates the socket closure as an empty message sent.

My code, because of a PEBKAC error, was not receiving the empty 0-byte messages, and thus I could never 'see' the graceful shutdown.

(In the event anyone has this issue in the future, the problem is that the ProcessReceive method should have called ReceiveAsync to continue the loop after receiving its first signal, and it... wasn't, for reasons unrelated to the code.)